# Iterating through a row and removing a matched cell - no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is to iterate through a `tr` containing a few `td`s and remove the first one which has the specified string (each cell contains a word and there can be only one match).
Here is the part that causing the problem:

```
$('#row > td').each(function () {
    if($(this).text() == 'something')
    {
        $("#row").remove($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAVry/1/)

I also tried with `$('#row').children()` instead of `$('#row > td')` with the same problem.
The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'
```

Let me know if there are more information required. I would appreciate any help that where I'm going wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `remove()` doesn't really have any parameters, you should be doing just `$(this).remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#row").remove($(this));
```

to

```
$(this).remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hAVry/3/)**

You're already iterating over the table cells, so `$(this)` is what you want to use with `.remove()`

Answer (score 2):

What you need is

```
$('#row > td').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'something';
}).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8N7Eu/)

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I go with j08691's answer though as it's closer to what I was doing.